# Sound plays on headphones and speakers at the same time with Lenovo ThinkPad

Tags: 10.04, hardware, sound, laptop

The only thing really missing from this install is this issue with the sound. I've searched all over the forums and i found one thing where you get the model and codecs and write them to a file, however, I can't seem to find what my "model" is because none of the postings have anything about Lenovo laptops. Here is the command they all asked for: Code:

```
cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#* | grep Codec
Codec: Realtek ALC269
Codec: Intel G45 DEVIBX
```

With that info, how do I get the model, and how do I get my speakers to stop playing when headphones are plugged in. Also, if i manually change the output device to headphones itll play just headphones in the sys prefs... so it CAN work, but it doesn't.

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad L512 as well.

Thanks so much to whoever can answer this...

The Ubuntu forums are nearly useless... ive never gotten a correct answer back on that site.

Also, i've filed a bug report and i know it's the ALSA plugin, i don't know how to fix it though.

Comment: What are your alsamixers like? Run "alsamixer -c0" (no quotes) in a terminal.

Comment: http://yfrog.com/6coscargodsonubuntu005p -- ?

Comment: All you can really do is wait for the bug to be fixed.  I'm assuming you either included alsa-info.sh output or used `ubuntu-bug linux` or `ubuntu-bug -s audio` to include debugging info

Comment: The mixer channel to do so is usually called front. It might be pulse restricting it. EDIT: I see you have no front. You can use the M key to mute a channel. Try playing with the mixers.

Comment: This question appears to be abandonded, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround:

Go to "sound preferences" and select the "Output" tab. There select "Analog Output" in the connector option.

Comment: No sound comes out at all when I do that in either headphones or speakers.

Comment: Check alsamixer after you do that, the channel might have just been muted.

Comment: Yeah, it was muted, but if i unmute it then it gets unmuted whether the headphones are plugged in or not. :(

Answer (score 0):

Where is your LP bug? I don't see it listed anywhere.

I wonder if we're setting a quirk incorrectly in /sbin/alsa-utils. That gets fired off on hotplug events.

As a quick test, you could comment out this line:

```
    exec /sbin/alsa-utils start $N
```

which can be found in /lib/udev/alsa-utils. Commenting it out will prevent the hotplug script from firing. Reboot after you comment it out, and see if that improves behavior any.

Comment: That didn't do anything. I think the issue is more that it's acting as if it WERE commented out. When I plug it in no event fires at all to change anything.

Comment: What is the LP bug with all your information?