# Lenovo - E420s - sound from laptop speakers and headphones

Tags: 14.04, sound, alsa, headphones

All of a sudden, sound from all applications plays from both speakers and headphones when I plug in the headphones.

I've checked [lots](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150887/sound-from-both-headphones-and-speakers) [of](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4727/sound-plays-on-headphones-and-speakers-at-the-same-time-with-lenovo-thinkpad) [similar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195661/both-speakers-and-headphone-are-giving-sound-how-to-fix-it?lq=1) questions but they all apply to older versions of Ubuntu and/or other hardware, and I haven't found a solution yet.  I do however have a workaround.

My workaround for now is:

This line at the end of the alsa conf `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

```
options snd-hda-intel model=lenovo
```

and then in `alsa-mixer` I have set the volume for `Speaker` to 00.  If I mute the Speaker, no sound comes from the headphones nor from the speakers.

Notes:

- In alsa-mixer `Auto-Mute Mode` is set to `Enabled`
- Laptop is a Lenovo ThinkPad E420s
- This has started in the last week, and the kernel was updated on 13/01/2015
- The headphones work normally with other devices (phone etc).
- It's not specific to any application.
- There are no options in the Sound Settings dialog that help (or that haven't been clicked to death already)

My codecs:

```
msturdy@mariachi:~$ cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec  
Codec: Conexant CX20590   
Codec: Intel CougarPoint HDMI
```

Kernel:

```
msturdy@mariachi:~$ uname -a
Linux mariachi 3.13.0-44-generic #73-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 16 00:22:43 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any ideas or possible solutions?  I'm all ears!

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the same problem once I got the most recent updates.

I see you're also using alsa-mixer. If you're using it because PulseAudio was giving you problems, then my solution might work.

It seems that PulseAudio got reinstalled (at least partially) with this round of updates. Once I removed Pulse, which you can do with this command:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove pulseaudio
```

(with more tips if need be in [these instructions](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/01/how-to-remove-pulseaudio-use-alsa-ubuntu-linux/)) I was able to reconfigure my speakers and headphones again in alsa-mixer, and everything works.

I hope that'll do it for you. (Thanks for the tip, Mitch)

Comment: Thanks Gurk!  I was using the alsa-mixer just to debug this issue, normally I just use the volume settings dialog through the task bar at the top right.  I'll have a look and see if anything changed in PulseAudio recently.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @gurk I can't see any changes to the Pulse Audio packages in some time, so I don't think it's that.